# May we have guidelines for use of the term "demigod" to refer to Hindu deities?

Tags: discussion

There are works deemed as scripture by HSE that use the term and I am not talking about those.

I mean use of the term in posters' own words:

[Who is more powerful - Indra or Yama?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/51142/who-is-more-powerful-indra-or-yama)

> Which demigod is more powerful - Yama or Indra ?

Indra is the most powerful deity in what maybe called the foundational scripture of Hinduism - the Rig Veda.

He is called Brahman:

[Which Vedic verses describe Indra as Brahman?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/19033/which-vedic-verses-describe-indra-as-brahman)

Is it considered good etiquette at HSE to refer to Indra as a "demigod"?

This term has hardly ever been used in English translations of Hindu scripture before the 1970s.

this term, applied to beloved Hindu deities, is hurtful to many Hindus (as can be evidenced here and websites like quora). It would be good if HSE had a policy about it.

Comment: *"Is it considered good etiquette at HSE to.."* - YES

Comment: Although, I personally don't like to use the term. I find the term "deva (देव/देवी)" more useful and exact. However, If it's used in the translation by a recognized sect or organization of Hinduism (like ISCKON), then there is little one can do (or should do), because that's how that acharya sees the term. And instead of getting offended, we might try to ignore those translation that are perceived incendiary to particular users, despite they are correct or not. "Correctness" is very broad and subjective in Hinduism, atleast in regard to interpretation of scriptures and Sanskrit words.